# Sunspot/Solr not able to search by boolean value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, solr, sunspot, websolr

I have a RoR model with a boolean field:

```
field :active, :type => Boolean
```

Which is listed in the searchable block:

```
searchable do
  boolean :active
```

And also in the search query:

```
s = Document.search do
  with(:active, true)
end
```

And also in my Solr schema.xml file:

```
<field name="active_b" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

The issue is that my search is not restricting the results to only documents with active set to true. This is working in my local development environment but not in Heroku.

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't the field be active_b in RoR??

Comment: Try uploading your schema.xml to heroku. If  heroku is using an different schema.xml. Or try reindexing your data on heroku...

Comment: I'm having the same problem with booleans but am not using Heroku.  Did you get this workign?

Answer (score 1):

If it's working in development then this is a deployment or Heroku issue, not a solr/sunspot issue.

From the Heroku docs https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websolr

Websolr provides a control panel at http://websolr.com/ where you may make changes to your index, such as adding or removing different Solr features, selecting a different Solr client, providing your own schema.xml and so on.

You will need to upload your schema.xml to Websolr.

Comment: This is correct. You'll also want to reindex once the change is made. Source: I operate websolr :)

Answer (score 1):

For me, this was a matter of using

```
with :deleted, false
```

when it evidently needs to be:

```
with :deleted, 0
```

Not sure if you were having the same problem as me though.